# Can I move Spring Boot logging settings out of application.properties file and into an untracked file?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging

I am working on building a SpringBoot app with my workmates.  We all have different preferred logging levels for the app.  We have been battling back and forth with each other's logging changed to application.properties.  Is there a way to move all of the `logging.level.*` stuff out of that application.properties file and into a ~logging.properties file or something?  That way we can add that file to the .gitignore and not track that file so we can each leave our logging alone.  We are using Java annotations and not xml btw.

I've tried adding `@PropertySource("classpath:logging.properties")`  to the application file, but I read somewhere that the logging gets setup early on in the init process and this won't work.  I tried it anyway and it doesn't work (so confirmed I guess).

I can't believe there's isn't more info on this out there.. I'd imagine the members of a dev team each want their own custom level of logging and don't want to keep stepping on each other's toes/commits.

Answer (score 1):

You can just override it using a command line property. The fallback strategy will take command line -D args as the highest overriding priority.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config

Comment: Yea, I guess setting `-Dspring.profiles.active=foo,bar` on the command line (or VM option in IntelliJ) might be the best route.  Then there can be sane defaults in applications.properties, but then MY specific properties in the application-bar.properties file, which seems to override application.properties settings.  Each dev can then set `bar` to whichever prop file they want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to have `logback.xml` file inside `resources/` with some defaults that works for everyone (more likely to the application in question) and then you can provide `--logging.config=/path/to/your/very/custom/logback.xml` file whenever you start the application *locally*.

That should work for everyone.

Comment: Thanks.  We are trying to avoid xml config, but this may be an option.